# Bitbucket server on CentOS

Tags: git, centos, bitbucket

I am trying to install a BitBucket server on CentOS on some company machine. Straight away it gives me a warning:

```
Unsupported Git version found [1.8.3.1]. Please upgrade Git to a supported
version before installing Bitbucket.
See http://go.atlassian.com/installgit for more information.
NOTE: If you proceed without a working Git, Bitbucket won't be able to start
after installation until a working Git is found.
If you proceed without a working Git, Bitbucket won't be able to start after installation.
Are you sure you want to continue?
```

Ok, I'm finding a solution [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-Install-Unsupported-Git-Message/qaq-p/649721), and following some steps get to the point where I have

```
[foo@foohost tmp]$ git --version
git version 2.14.2
```

Nice, this even works after restarting the bash, since I added the path to the new git to `~/.bashrc`. I try installing the BitBucket again, and get the same error as above. Strange, but whatever - I ignore it, install the server, start it and get the following:

[image: Error]

What should I do?

Update: I have noticed that when I do `sudo git --version`, I still get the old version there.

Answer (score 2):

The modification of `PATH` in your `~/.bashrc` only affects you (due to the `~`) and only affects `bash`.

There are other locations such as `/etc/profile.d/` or others (this tends to be slightly distribution specific) where such systemwide modifications are better made.

Note also that you probably should be running bitbucket as a separate, limited user for security purposes. But you probably already knew that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am not sure exactly what you have meant with the latter statement: other users seem to be able to access that service through their browsers, but until I've created users for them, they can'd to much there. Regarding the PATH: clear - so what would be the best way to tell `sudo` where to look for the new git?

Comment: Well, sudo (rather the root user) does not really need to know specifically. Under what local Unix user are you running the bitbucket services? I hope it's not root, and I hope it's something like a `bitbucket` user. You'll need to ensure that `bitbucket`'s `PATH` is set up properly in a noninteractive context (here I'm assuming you're using a `systemd` or similar service to actually start the BitBucket's processes. I'm not familiar with CentOS to provide you with the right answer. Their documentation should definitely contain things like this.

Comment: Yeah, on the start it's written `Starting Atlassian Bitbucket as dedicated user atlbitbucket`. So now even in root env the git is fine, and at least I don't get the error on installation. Still, the error appears in the web service. Any chance to know, which PATH variable does this web service use?

Comment: In `ps -ef | grep bucket` I do see `atlbitbucket` as the owner of those processes, however no `/home/` subfolder exists for this user. If I create one and provide there PATH update in `bashrc`, should that help?

Comment: @Ilya No, the user's home directory is probably something like `/var/lib/atlbitbucket`. You can find out by doing `echo ~atlbitbucket`. You could try `.bashrc`, but I think it won't be used for non-interactive shells (which is probably what is used to launch the process.

Comment: thanks, I've just overwritten the old git everywhere

Comment: @Ilya it would be useful for the rest of the world to know exactly how you solved your problem ;)

Comment: I guess my last comment answers that

Comment: I guess it doesn't. There are various ways to "overwrite the old git everywhere"